# JBoss 7.1 AS - The LogManager was not properly installed

Tags: jboss7.x, ehcache

I am getting the following exception in JBoss AS 7.1:

*The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")*

(full trace appended at the end of the post).

I've read a [relevant discussion](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1) on JBoss Issue Tracker, but although I 've set my JAVA_OPTS and CLASSPATH as indicated (this is from my **standalone.conf**):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar"
```

... I keep getting the same logging exception.

**TRACE:**

```
Exception: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:60) [jboss-client.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.SerializedLogger.readResolve(SerializedLogger.java:54) [jboss-client.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1780) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.SimpleSession.readObject(SimpleSession.java:500) [shiro-all-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:498) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at net.sf.ehcache.Element.readObject(Element.java:844) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:324) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub.send(Unknown Source) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:314) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.replicationThreadMain(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:127) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.access$000(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:58) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator$ReplicationThread.run(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:389) [ehcache-core-ee-2.6.0.jar:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ever helpful JBoss community [I received the advice](https://community.jboss.org/message/757952#757952) to change non-static **Logger** members in my classes to static whereupon the issue disappeared. At the time of this writing the jury's still out on whether this is a JBoss bug or not. It is interesting however that the [very first bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1) (so very first that looking at the URL you may be mistaken to think it is non-bookmarkable) lodged in JBoss JIRA against JBoss AS 7 is again the very same **LogManager** exception.